# Angular Typeahead where model as an Id and Text as a name of the array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

I'm using [Angular UI Typeahead directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/j8HYZRN1SafyrI5EMf4g).So could you tell me how can I set a `model` as an `id` and `display text` as a `name` on it.I have tried like below.But it's not working.How can I do that ? Thanks.

**Note :** Please type `a` or `k` on the below code pen to test it.

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Sampath-Lokuge/pen/bpqdEO)

**JS**

```
 var states=[{'id':1,'name':'Alabama'},{'id':2,'name':'Kansas'}]
```

**Html**

```
    <input name="states" id="states" type="text" placeholder="enter a state" ng-
model="selected" typeahead="a.id as a.name for a in states | filter:$viewValue" 
class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you try to only put selected state `id` inside `ng-model` then it will only show up `id` of selected state inside that input field, as `ng-model` only has `id` value in it.

So basically you have to select whole object instead of just putting id inside `ng-model`. By which when any state is selected `a as a.name` expression will only show `name` from it. And you could use `selected.id` whenever you want to  pass state `id`.

**Markup**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="states">Search for US States</label>
  <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
  <input name="states" id="states" type="text" 
     placeholder="enter a state" ng-model="selected" 
     typeahead="a as a.name for a in states | filter:$viewValue" 
     class="form-control">
</div>
```

[**Forked Codepen**](http://codepen.io/pankajparkar/pen/mPWJOK)

Comment: Thanks a lot.One question thought : It's working fine when I select an item from the list.But when I try to type a non existing item then the `model` doesn't work as an object.It shows like this : `selected : "wsdef"`.Is there any way to show it is also as like this : `selected : id:null,name:"wsdef"` or as an object like the other scenario ? Thanks.